# SSPI configuration for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-16

I am trying to set up SSPI for PostgreSQL 16 DB.
I have edited the pg_ident.conf & pg_hba.conf

pg_ident.conf

## MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME

Mapname accountname@domainname      accountname

pg_hba.conf

## TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all             accountname       127.0.0.1/32            sspi  map=Mapname
host    all             accountname       ::1/128                 sspi  map=Mapname

After restarting the service SSPI does not work.
From the trouble shooting it seems that the SSPI entries on the pg_hba.conf is not recognised at all.

When all other entries are commented I get the error -
connection failed: :1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption

Can any body advice? If I am missing something?

Comment: "From the trouble shooting it seems that the SSPI entries on the pg_hba.conf is not recognised at all."  Please tell us what you observed, not just your interpretation of what you observed.  did you get `invalid authentication method "sspi": not supported by this build`?

Comment: Thanks for your response @jjanes. When all other lines in the pg_hba are commented I see the following message -"FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption". If the other lines are not commented - then I see the message -"Connection matched file "Path/PostgreSQL/pg_hba.conf" line 122: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256"".  Line 122 is lower in the pg_hba. So to my conclusion it does not consider the entries for SSPI which is written before line 122.